# How to change the setup/installation screen?

Tags: 20.04, lts

I want to change the installation screen on 20.04. For example, I want to change the background of the screen, slideshow, and the terms and conditions. How do I change it? Thanks.

Comment: Change the packages involved (eg. `ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu` if using a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using `ubiquity` but you weren't specific as to which 20.04 LTS ISO you mean) etc. OR change the seed (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu.focal/desktop though you may mean a different SEED to this one as there are a number for 20.04 LTS representing different ISOs) of the ISO you create etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by changing terms and conditions, but Ubuntu does contain some restricted intellectual property.  You also have to abide by the licensing of individual software.  Most copyleft software requires that you keep the same license and do not make any deviations. https://ubuntu.com/legal/intellectual-property-policy